# Adding fragment below toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, toolbar

I have an `activity.xml`.

As you can see, it's a relative layout. I am hoping that the Frame layout which will contain the fragment, will be below the toolbar.

The fragment is added, for sure. But it's added at the top, covering the toolbar. Just wondering what I am doing wrong.

The website wouldn't let me add code for some reason. It was telling me it's not properly formatted. here is the activity.xml layout.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <!--scroll|snap-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolBarHeight"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appToolBar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is simply what I am doing in the Activity.java file.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, SetupFrag.createInstance(false), SETUP_FRAGMENT).commit();
```

Comment: Check your ToolBar height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an existing id, `@android:id/content`

You should use `+` to add your own ID, `@+id/content`, otherwise the fragment is being added to the content view (the level above your activity layout).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't under the impression that id was reserved. I thought I could use it just like I used @android:id/list. From now and on, I will create my own IDs instead of using platform default IDs.

Comment: `@android:id/list` is also reserved ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different root Layout.

RelativeLayout will layout its children relatively to each other.
What you want instead is a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolBarHeight"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why OP's layout isn't working.

Comment: @android:id/content is a reserved id (use by the system for the root of your activity)

Comment: This didn't work either. I was using the shared platform ID, which was messing up things.